# Initializing a string using a given pointer

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

My function receives 2 variables:
`char* str`, and  `int cap`.

The `str` variable is an empty array of chars, and I'm trying to initialize a new type of string called NEW, s.t NEW:

> - As in regular strings, the prefix of the character array before the    first '\0' character defines the string.
> - The string is followed by a non-empty sequence of '\0' characters, followed by the character    '\1', which signifies the end of NEW.

Do I need to dynamically allocate memory for the initialization of NEW? 
If not, what is the right syntax to use this pointer?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If `str` points to the first element of an empty array, then how are you supposed to initialize anything based on it?

Comment: Is this school work/teacher's question?

Comment: Do you know to what exactly str points to? if it points to a char array that's already being allocated then you don't need to allocate memory

Answer (score 1):

If you're not given an allocated memory, then yes, you must dynamically allocate it yourself.

Basically if your function receives a char * I'd assume the called already allocated memory and passes it to you for initialization, in that case, I'd do:

```
   initialize_NEW(char *str, int cap) 
   {
        memset(str, 0, cap);
        str[cap-1] = '\1';
        ...
   }
```

Assuming cap is the length of the char array passed.

If you're supposed to initialize the memory, I'd figure the function should look something like:

```
   initialize_NEW(char **str, int cap) 
   {
        *str = malloc(cap);
        if (!(*str)) { /* Malloc error handling here */
        memset(str, 0, cap);
        (*str)[cap-1] = '\1';
        ...
   }
```

Ideally, you want to free memory from the same function you called it - but in the case where you given a memory to initialize, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: In second example `str` is of type `char **` . `str[cap-1]` is of type `char *` . _To assign a character you need to dereference it one more time_ .

Comment: what is `'\1'` supposed to be

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yet I'm not sure if the memory has already been allocated for me.
Can you suggest an efficient way to verify it?

Comment: @ameyCU Correct, woes of the copy paste, thanks!

It's supposed to be a special char instructed to signify the end of the NEW type string (from original question)

Comment: @user43101 - You'll have to check with your instructor, it isn't possible to verify whether a pointer is pointing to an allocated memory or not, maybe in a specific implementation you can, but in general, you can't.


Basically, a way to do it would move back 4 bytes from the pointer and see if there's a metadata from the malloc call (that would be used when a free is called on that pointer) - but that's implementation specific, there is no standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to dynamically allocate memory for the initialization of NEW?

Since you are receiving a pointer to an array of `char`s as a parameter, you do not need to do any allocation.

Since the result must be filled with zeros after the "payload" portion of the string, I suggest using [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy), which fills the "tail" of the string with zeros. All you need to do after that is setting `'\1'` into the last byte.